# Ubuntu-Arch Linux: Key based Authentication

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, arch-linux, key-authentication

I am trying to setup keybased authentication between Arch Linux and Ubuntu. Both OS are virtual installations(I know this doesnt matter but just FYI).

I have generated ssh key's with default options by using `ssh-keygen` command on both Arch and Ubuntu machines, And then copied public keys with `ssh-copy-id` command.

I am able to login from Arch machine to Ubuntu machine successfully.

```
[raja@archserver ~]$ ssh sniper@192.168.106.106
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-57-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


Last login: Tue Jan 10 16:30:51 2017 from 192.168.106.1
sniper@openstackm1:~$
```

But I am unable to login via key-based authentication from Arch machine to Ubuntu machine and when I tried I am getting prompt for password. I havent done any modifications to both sshd_config files but Ubuntu accepting but Arch doesnt.

```
sniper@openstackm1:~$ ssh jboss@archserver
jboss@archserver's password:
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you get any additional insights when using the `-v` flag on your failing `ssh` command? `ssh -v jboss@archserver`

Comment: @To close over , Why it is too broad ? You ask me what you need to understand and I am ready to provide that information. You have right to have your opinion but making your opinion as a statement isnt right.

Comment: @Emeric may be due to this ? `debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/sniper/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`

Comment: Yes, that looks like a plausible cause. OpenSSH does not like DSA too much anymore. If you don't have the option to generate other types of keys (rsa would be likely valid), you can add `+ssh-dss` in your `ssh_config` to allow it.

Comment: @Emeric Thank you , I am working on it. I will let you know.

Comment: @Emeric Excellent , Thank you. Its working now. Please add it as answer.

Comment: Alternately, create a new RSA or ECDSA key instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSH does not like DSA too much anymore, and started disabling it by default. If you don't have the option to generate other types of keys (rsa would be likely valid), you can add `+ssh-dss` in your `ssh_config` to allow it.